# Copying File into hidden folder

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-7, group-policy, copy, robocopy

I'm attempting to copy a URL link for our companies library system onto all users workstation desktops. I've tried creating a shortcut via Group policy:
*User Configuration > Preferences > Windows Settings > Shortcuts* however from what I can tell, this doesn't work onto Windows 7 machines as they're common desktop directories are different. (Running Server 2008 *not R2*.)

I've also tried copying the shortcut from a server location to the directory C:\Users\Public\Public Desktop. However I'm running into issues as the *Public Desktop* folder is a hidden folder. Running a command such as

`copy "\\server\folder\link.url" "c:\users\public\public desktop\"`
does not work as the *public desktop* folder is hidden, so it just returns a directory not found error.

I have also tried running `robocopy \\server\folder\ "c:\users\public\public desktop" link.url` This however just results in robocopy creating another non hidden folder 'Public Desktop' next the the hidden one in the 'c:\users\public' folder.

Similarly using the GPO *User Configuration > Preferences > Windows Settings > Files* to try and copy it in yields no result. For the same reason being the destination folder is a hidden folder.

Is there any way I can manipulate either GPO or some copy/robocopy command to place the file into the preexisting hidden folder for all our Windows 7 workstations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't that it's hidden, it's that you're using the wrong path. You want to copy it to `c:\users\public\desktop`